# Where did I make a mistake solving $x^3-6x^2+2x+3=0$ with Cardano's method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, cubics

> Solve $x^3-6x^2+2x+3=0$ for $x$

Here's my attempt at solving it via Cardano's Method as it applies to the general cubic:

$$x^3-6x^2+2x+3=0$$
\begin{align*}y&=x+\frac{b}{3a} \\ y&= x+\frac{-6}{3} \\ y &= x-2 \\ y+2&=x\end{align*}
Substitute $x$ for $y+2$
$$(y+2)^3-6(y+2)^2+2(y+2)+3=0$$
Expand out
$$y^3+6y^2+12y+8-6y^2-24y-24+2y+4+3=0$$
Add like terms to get the depressed cubic
$$y^3-10y-9=0$$
$$y=u+v$$
Substitute $y$ for $u+v$
$$y^3=(u+v)^3$$
\begin{align*}(u+v)^3 &= u^3+3u^2v+3uv^2+v^3 \\ &= u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v) \\ &= u^3+v^3+3uvy\end{align*}
$$y^3=u^3+v^3+3uvy$$
Make the right side equal to $0$ to get the depressed cubic in terms of $u$, $v$, and $y$
$$y^3-3uvy-(u^3+v^3)=0$$
\begin{align*}-3uv &= -10 & u^3+v^3 &= 9 & uv &=\frac{10}{3}\end{align*}
$$u^3v^3=\frac{10^3}{3^3}=\frac{1000}{27}$$
Factored form of desired quadratic
$$(t-u^3)(t-v^3)=0$$
Expand out the quadratic
\begin{align*}t^2-(u^3+v^3)t+u^3v^3 &= 0 \\ t^2-9t+\frac{1000}{27} &= 0\end{align*}
Can't factor quadratic, use the quadratic formula to solve for $t$
$$t=\frac{9\pm \sqrt{81-\frac{4000}{108}}}{2}$$
Simplify the square root
$$t=\frac{9 \pm \frac{\sqrt{3561}}{9}}{2}$$
Simplify the fraction
$$t=\frac{81 \pm \sqrt{3561}}{18}$$
Take cube root of the entire fraction to get $u$ and $v$
\begin{align*}u &= \sqrt[3]{\frac{81 + \sqrt{3561}}{18}} \\ v &=\sqrt[3]{\frac{81 - \sqrt{3561}}{18}}\end{align*}
Simplify root expression
\begin{align*}u &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{972+12\sqrt{3561}}}{6} \\ v &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{972-12\sqrt{3561}}}{6} \\\\ y &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{972+12\sqrt{3561}}+\sqrt[3]{972-12\sqrt{3561}}}{6} \\\\ x &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{972+12\sqrt{3561}}+\sqrt[3]{972-12\sqrt{3561}}}{6}+2\end{align*}

Now, to check that I got this wrong, I checked for the roots of the original cubic using a calculator, and this is what I should have gotten for $x$:

$$x= \left\{1, \frac{5+\sqrt{37}}{2}, \frac{5-\sqrt{37}}{2}\right\}$$

But instead, I got a whole mess of cube roots and square roots, so I definitely made a mistake somewhere trying to solve this cubic using Cardano's Method. **So where is that mistake that led to the whole mess of $n$th roots?**

Comment: Check the discriminant in your quadratic solution $4\times 1000/27 \neq 4000/108$. BTW, testing for rational roots first and then dividing by the linear factor to isolate the quadratic is how i would go solving this cubic.

Comment: You are aware you don't have to use the general cubic method at all here, right?

Comment: @Deepak Yeah, I know that, but ever since I learned about the general cubic method, I have wanted to test it out myself. And so I found a cubic equation online and decided to try solving it with the general cubic method.

Comment: +1 to your posted question for presenting your work in a very clear and thorough manner.  The fact that there is some hidden analytical error in your work is irrelevant to evaluating the quality of your posted question.

Answer (score 2):

As @Macavity stated, the part where you went wrong is when you solved for the value of $t$. You multiplied both the numerator and the denominator by $4$ when in fact, only the numerator should be multiplied.

It's recommended that you first try to use the rational root theorem before resorting to this formula. You can't rely on formulas like this, especially if its degree is greater than five. However, if you really want to use Cardano's formula, it will be easier if you skip the "completing the cube" process and use a summary. Check out the formula from [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula).

> The solutions of the general cubic formula $$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$$ for $a \neq 0$ are \begin{align*}x_1 &= S + T - \frac{b}{3a} \\ x_2 &= -(S + T) - \frac{b}{3a} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}(S - T) \\ x_3 &= -(S + T) - \frac{b}{3a} - \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}(S - T)\end{align*}
> where \begin{align*}S &= \sqrt[3]{R + \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2}} \\ T &= \sqrt[3]{R - \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2}}\end{align*}
> and \begin{align*}Q &= \frac{3ac - b^2}{9a^2} \\ R &= \frac{9abc - 27a^2d - 2b^3}{54a^3}.\end{align*}

> The expression $D = Q^3 + R^2$ is the **discriminant** of the equation.
>
> If:
>
> - $D > 0$, then one root is real and the other two are complex conjugates.
> - $D = 0$, then all roots are real and at least two are equal.
> - $D < 0$, then all roots are real and unequal.

---

> But instead, I got a whole mess of cube roots and square roots, so I definitely made a mistake somewhere trying to solve this cubic using Cardano's Method.

A messy-looking expression made up of nested roots compared to a simpler-looking expression doesn't mean that one of them is a mistake. It's just that solving expressions involving nested roots are more prone to mistakes.

Compare the following expressions: $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sqrt[3]{5 + \sqrt[3]{324} + \sqrt[3]{486}}$. Although it is quite hard to see, they are equal.

In your case, your solution will eventually get to the point where $$t = \frac{9 \pm \sqrt{-\frac{1813}{27}}}{2}.$$ By letting complex numbers at play, you will have to take its cube root later. For instance, $$u = \sqrt[3]{\frac{9 \pm i\sqrt{\frac{1813}{27}}}{2}}$$ This is the so-called [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis). Refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/717715/888233) to know how to get the real solutions.

Comment: Note that the original cubic has three real roots, it is automatic that the cube roots apply to non-real complex numbers, in the that square root must be of a negative real, as you have. If the roots were irrational this would be Casus Irreducibilis

Comment: @WillJagy I am sorry. I don't understand what you said.

Comment: Alright, you do mention casus irreducibils;  I was just saying that three real roots means the cube roots are automatically of non-real complex numbers; as the original question had cube roots of real numbers, there was an error before that point in the OP's calculation.

Comment: I believe I mentioned that error. I cited Macavity's comment about it. I also added some details about their statement about having a whole mess of cube roots and square roots which led to my introduction on casus irreducibilis.